# htaccess - Deny php file access but allow a specific folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a website paytrics.com

This site is working on Codeigniter. I have written a piece of code in htaccess to block direct access of php files. The code is

[Please see this image for htacess code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRN50.png)

This is working fine. However, here is my problem. 
I have installed wordpress inside a folder paytrics.com/blog
The pages and posts of blog are opening properly.

But since I have blocked access wp-admin of blog
So, when I open http://www.paytrics.com/blog/wp-admin it gives me an error that permission is denied.

How to solve this problem? I want direct access of php files denied in my codeigniter project, but I also need to access Wordpress admin section.

Comment: Why would you block it? I'd put a password on the folder and rename it to something like /ad-access/.

Comment: I am blocking php files because I noticed people can use upload file hack to upload php files and execute them. So I want php files prevented for execution directly.

Comment: The good old c99 days. Anyway, if you update wordpress to the latest versions, they won't be able to use scripts like c99. Besides, uninstall any file upload related plug-ins as they are often unsecured. As long as you keep updating wordpress you're good to go.

Comment: Actually I know WP will prevent it. However, WP is in Blog folder installed. This htaccess is for codeigniter project which is in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, if you are trying to access `/wp-admin` page. It actually redirects to `/wp-login.php` page. Because WordPress authentication and redirects are managed inside `/wp-login.php` page.

Since you are blocking access to .php files, try to create an alias for the WordPress directory.

Update your host entry to following,

```
Alias /blog/ /var/www/wordpress_path
<Directory /var/www/wordpress_path/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then the .htaccess inside your WordPress install should work, then you can login to the backend.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I reckon this. Good one!

Comment: Nikhil. I tried yours but it did not work. I think I used incorrect code. Can you please customize for my website and share code?

I have public_html folder. Then Paytrics folder where CI project is located and then inside it I have blog folder for WP project. Now what code should I use?

Comment: Do you have access to server? SSH?

Comment: Yes I have access to server and I can enable SSH connections. However, I do not know how to use SSH shell and things. I am using Bluehost as host server. Please guide buddy I will be grateful.

Comment: I think you are using shared hosting. If yes, contact the provider and ask them to add an alias to the configuration of 'www.paytrics.com'. Alias details is added in the answer. If you are using VPS then it is easy you can do the update. But I need more information on the server config to give an exact way to make this happen. I prefer contacting bluehost and ask them to add alias.

Comment: I use to fix these kind of issues by adding alias to the directory. Then if you navigate to blog it should point to exact directory (not to the parent directory).  I've experienced this more than a couple of times.

Comment: Thanks I will contact them. What should I say them? Just ask them to add an alias? Or add alias for....???
Second - In your code wordpress_path will be?
Folder name like its blog?

Comment: folder_name specifies the root location where WordPress install located. Just ask them to add an alias for /blog to the WordPress directory and see what they are saying.

Comment: Sorry to bother once again. Just to clarify I have a shared host with 3 domains. Paytrics is one of them. So it is in the public html folder with paytrics folder. and then blog is inside it. So, I would ask them to add an alias for paytrics.com to the blog directory (which is wp directory)?

Comment: You should be having,
Root website directory (paytrics.com) -> Inside that -> Blog directory (WordPress install).  Ask them to add Alias for blog directory in the config of paytrics.com.

Comment: Thanks buddy I will ask them and see what they have to say.